# Clang-format breaks #include double quotes

Tags: clang, clang-format

I am a newbie for Clang-Format.

I use ./bin/clang-format -style=google -dump-config > .clang-format as my base .clang-format.

Based on that, I changed some parameters for my customized demands.

However, after I change the column_limits from 80 to 0(I just want break the lines using my personal decision), all my `#include "header.h"` become:

```
#include \ 
      "header.h"
```

It's weird. I have be struggling with this for a whole day. But the problem is still in there.

By the way, all my #include  do not have this problem

Could anyone give me some clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that has been fixed by now. Use a more recent version and this problem will go away.